# Python accessing slices of a list in order

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, slice

In Python 2.7, I have a list named `data`, with some tuples, indexed by the first attribute, e.g.

```
data = [('A', 1, 2, 3), ('A', 10, 20, 30), ('A', 100, 200, 300),
        ('B', 1, 2, 3), ('B', 10, 20, 30),
        ('C', 15, 25, 30), ('C', 1, 20, 22), ('C', 100, 3, 8)]
```

There is a function `f()` that will work on any slice of `data` with the first index matching, e.g.

`f( [x[1:] for x in data[:3] )`

I want to call `f` (in proper sequence) on each slice of the array (group of tuples with the same first index) and compile the list of resulting values in a list.

I'm just starting with Python. Here is my solution, is there a better (faster or more elegant) way to do this?

```
slices = [x for x in xrange(len(data)) if data[x][0] != data[x-1][0]]
result = [f(data[start:end] for start, end in zip( [slices[:-1], slices[1:] )]
```

Thank you.

Comment: It is not clear what you are trying to achieve here. Do you mean you want to call `f()` on each *group* of tuples, where they are grouped on the first item in each tuple?

Comment: If your data is indexed by the first attribute, how can you differentiate between the As, Bs or Cs?

Comment: `data[x][0] != data[x][-1]` is always true in `data`. This means you basically creating a sliding window of size two across `data`.

Comment: @gt6989b: exactly, what? Sorry, I made two statements; did you want to group on the first key of the tuples, or did you want to create a sliding window of size 2 across `data`?

Comment: @MartijnPieters you are right, sorry for the typo - changed it now, needs to be `data[x][0] != data[x-1][0]`

Comment: @MartijnPieters group by the first key. Sorry for the confusion. This is what my slice extraction does...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to group on the first item of each tuple, you can do so with [`itertools.groupby()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby):

```
from itertools import groupby
from operator import itemgetter

[f(list(g)) for k, g in groupby(data, key=itemgetter(0))]
```

The `itemgetter(0)` returns the first element of each tuple, which `groupby()` then gives you iterables for each group based on that value. Looping over each individual `g` result will then give you a sequence of tuples with just `'A'`, then `'B'`, etc.